# Erro ao adicionar compilação do APP em iTunes Connect

Tags: xcode, itunes

Estou tentando subir uma atualização do meu APP para a loja
Mudei apenas conteúdos de algumas NSStrings, quando dou archive e envio ele pro iTunes, ele não apresenta nenhum erro, porem quando vou adicioná-lo, o iTunes não permite.

A única coisa que fiz foi atualizar meu xCode para a ultima versão (8.1).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Me mandaram esta mensagem:**

Dear developer,

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "APP Name". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:

This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

Regards,

The App Store team

---

Pelo que entendi, devo acrescentar algo na Info.plist
O que poderia ser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O app utiliza recursos de acesso a biblioteca de imagens e da câmera do usuário.

> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage
>   description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to
>   the user how the app uses this data.
>
> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage
>   description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the
>   user how the app uses this data.

Ambas as mensagens são claras quanto a isso e pedem para adicionar no "Info.plist" os parâmetros que informam ao iOS do usuário sobre o uso dos recursos.

No "Info.plist", adicione

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Photo Library Access Warning</string>

<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the camera.</string>
```

Pode personalizar as mensagens porém, esteja ciente sobre localizações (diversos idiomas).

Para o usuário, será apresentada uma caixa de alerta assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sub>imagem ilustrativa</sub>

sobre o "Info.plist", esse é o nome padrão do arquivo, mas pode acontecer do seu projeto estar usando um nome customizado. De qualquer forma é fácil encontrar no XCode. Basta procurar arquivos que terminem com ".plist".

Para editar, pode usar um editor de textos e editar direto sem o XCode.

Você vai encontrar algo assim, é o formato XML

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pela interface do XCode, terá algo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sub>*As imagens são ilustrativas</sub>